# adb device missing

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and am now ready to publish it to my device (HTC Desire). The only thing is I am using ubuntu and I am having trouble doing so. I have found some help on the internet regarding installing the drivers, only I need something called "adb devices", however in the latest android sdk it has been moved and now I can't find it. The SDK is up to date. Has anyone else had trouble getting linux to recognize their HTC device?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTC devices work quite nicely under Linux, without any drivers whatsoever. I've used a HTC wildfire under ubuntu with no problems.

adb is an executable file. You can find it in the platform-tools subdirectory of the SDK. "devices" just a parameter to that command (adb devices lists all devices connected).

Comment: I think I might have got around it. I was looking in the wrong android-sdk folder.